# My boss is not letting me leave the job

Tags: job-change

My boss is not letting me leave the job. I have said so many times that I want to quit this job, but he is not letting me quit. Now tell me what to do. He wants me to continue the job but also not increasing my pay.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you please state your country of residence? But general advice is to check how to **legally** leave your job and how long does it **legally** take. For instance, in Czech Republic it takes one letter to write and two months before you can actually leave

Comment: Have you only used argument of leaving the job in pay-rise talks or did you put in termination letter according to the contract you have?

Comment: Not being allowed to leave makes this something other than "employment", and there are many terms for that "something other", none of them good.

Comment: In what way is he not letting you leave? What happens if you just don't turn up tomorrow morning?

Comment: I agree that we need way more information. What country are you in? How is your boss preventing you from leaving? I assume he's not chaining you the wall or something so we need to know the details in order to help.

Answer (score 8):

> I have said so ma any times that I want to quit this job but he is not letting me to Leave it.

He can't stop you leaving. He might not want you to, but that's another matter entirely - if he's somehow forcing you to stay, that's illegal in almost every country there is, and falls under the remit of modern slavery laws.

> He wants me to continue the job but also not increasing my pay.

Assuming he's not forcing you to stay, but just won't give you a pay rise, then you have two simple options:

- Stay on your current pay;
- Look for somewhere else with higher pay.

Assuming you want the pay rise, and think you'll get it elsewhere, then my advice is the same as to anyone in this situation - search for another job with higher pay that's a good fit, and when you've found it, hand in your notice.

Comment: This does depend on country. In some countries, India is an example, there are serious consequences of leaving a job without the agreement of the employer.

Answer (score -3):

In most every country on earth, slavery is illegal.
If you're indeed not allowed by your employer to quit your job, that's slavery and therefore illegal almost everywhere.

If that's the case, filing criminal charges may be in order.

But I seriously doubt that's the case, most likely he just doesn't want you to leave but is incapable for some reason to honour your request for a pay increase. In that case you can do either of 2 things:

1. look for another job elsewhere and hand in your resignation when you've found that job or
2. continue working for them in the hope that in the future they will be able to give you a pay increase (maybe there are economic reasons they can't?)

Seriously, in almost every country in the world (some places in Africa and maybe the Middle East excempted) it's illegal to refuse an employee from leaving your employment if the proper termination procedures for the contract (as set out in the contract and/or applicable law) are followed. No company worth working for would knowingly violate that, as they'd be in a whole lot of trouble (including prison time for the management and HR staff responsible).

Comment: This reads like a reworded copy of berry120's answer. If you want to suggest improvements to an existing answer, please use the comment function. Otherwise you should clarify how your answer differs from berry120's.